# Count Sentence Character

Tags: c

I have a problem.

I'd like to make a program that count the number of vowels in one sentence.

And to do that, I use strlen to count the number of letters in one sentence
but the problem is, why it only count the first word.

I need the number of characters in one sentence to loop the program to find the vowels in each word in the sentence.

How to count all the characters in one sentence?

which command should I use?

I'm using C Language

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    int input;

    int repeater;
    scanf("%d",&input);
    int counter[input];
    getchar();
    char kalimat[100000];
    scanf("%s",kalimat);
    for(int i=1;i<=input;i++)
    {
        counter[i]=0;
    }
    repeater=strlen(kalimat);
    for(int i=1;i<=input;i++)
    {
        for(int j=i;j<=repeater;j++)
        {
            if(kalimat[j]=='A'||kalimat[j]=='a'||kalimat[j]=='E'||kalimat[j]=='e'||kalimat[j]=='I'||kalimat[j]=='i'||kalimat[j]=='O'||kalimat[j]=='o'||kalimat[j]=='U'||kalimat[j]=='u')
            {
                counter[i]++;
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Do you know about `switch`? also, this `char kalimat[100000]` is not a good idea, and it's still not safe, it would be enough to `char kalimat[100]; scanf("%99[^\n]", kalimat)`.

Comment: you also forgot `y`, which is sometimes a vowel...

Comment: Aren't arrays indexed from 0 in C?

Comment: This `i=1;i<=input` should be `i=0;i<input`.

Comment: @MarcB: This is language depended. In German for example you have 3 more vowles, the Umlauts `öüä`.

Answer (score 5):

`scanf` is only grabbing up until the first space. You need to pass a pattern to `scanf` that accepts whitespace. Try replacing the `"%s"` with `"%[^\n]"`.

Comment: What's with the backslash in the conversion? Shouldn't that be `"[^\n]"`?

Comment: @EOF Good catch! I mistyped. I edited the answer to clear that up. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1. scanf only counts to the first spacer if you use "%s" as initiater.
2. char kalimat[100000]; is ugly, ugly coding and still not safe to overflow. Just limit the chars you can enter to 200 or so.
3. String indexes start with 0, so your i counter should, too.

Answer (score 0):

The `%s` conversion specifier tells `scanf` to read up to the next whitespace character; it won't read in multiple words separated by whitespace.

The safer approach would be

```
if ( !fgets( kalimat, sizeof kalimat, stdin ) )
{
  // error on input, handle as appropriate
}
else
{
  // process kalimat
}
```

Just be aware that `fgets` will store the trailing newline into `kalimat` if there's room.  And 10 kilobytes is a bit large for an auto array.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this, expand to other letters as needed, 'Y' maybe.

```
 #include <string.h>
 int main(  )
{
  int i = 0;
  int counter = 0;
  char c;
  char kalimat[100000];

  printf("\n please enter text\n");
  fgets( kalimat, 100000, stdin );

 for ( i = 0; i < strlen( kalimat ); i++ )
 {
  c = toupper( kalimat[i] );
  if ( c == 'A' || c == 'E' || c == 'I' || c == 'O' || c == 'U' )
   counter++;
 }
 printf( "\n I counted %d vowels ", counter );
 getchar(  );
}
```